# iOS certificate: Why am I getting an expiration notice?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, digital-certificate

I've been developing iOS enterprise apps for about 7 years now, and I still have trouble understanding the signing certificate stuff. I got an email from Apple warning me that my enterprise distribution certificate is set to expire on December 28, 2017. However, looking at my Keychain data, I see that the expiration date for that particular certificate is Oct 14, 2019. I don't see anything on the list that expires on December 28, 2017.

So I don't know what I am supposed to do: ignore it, and hope my users can continue to use the apps? Or renew it and recompile/redistribute?

Apple seems never to make things easy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: log into the developer account and check the expiration dates of provisioning profiles. The chances are your 'live' enterprise provisioning profile expires then

Comment: @Scriptable Thanks, I see that now. What should I do? Revoke it and renew it? And will that have any immediate effect on the apps' usage? EDIT: I now see that there is also a production certificate expiring Oct 2019, which matches the one in my keychain. Can I assume that it is the one that the apps are using, and don't need to worry about them crashing on Dec 29?

Comment: I'm no expert in Apple's certificates and provisioning but I'm presuming that your last upload to the store was using your currently expiring key and thats why your getting this warning via email. Personally, I would generate brand new provisioning profiles and prepare a release with the new profiles and then on the day that you release, revoke your old profiles. Someone may come along with a better/safer solution though

Comment: @Scriptable Thanks again. To be clear, these are enterprise apps, and do not go through the App Store. they are served from local servers. Do. you think that will make a difference?

Comment: That shouldn't make much difference, all of the provisioning and certificates work in a very similar (if not the same) way